# New TextView(this) in Class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

```
TextView myMsg = new TextView(this);
```

I am trying to instantiate a new TextView in a class but keep getting this error:

*TextView (android.content.Context) in TextView cannot be applied to (my.package.class.name)*

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Can you post the code of your Activity please?

Comment: Your class has to extend Context or a class that extends Context.

Comment: Thank you, AppPhil. getActivity() did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to pass in an Android Context as an argument for one of TextView's default constructor. A common sample would be a typical Activity as follows:

```
package my.package.class.name;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    }
}
```

... "this" as in AppCompatActivity which is a subclass of the Context class as shown [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).